# How to run jar file using docker file in docker container

Tags: java, docker, jar, executable-jar, dockerfile

I write the docker file for run the jar file and it does not create the log file for see the console below is my docker file

```
From ubuntu 
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    apt-get clean
VOLUME /temp
RUN apt-get install -y vim
ADD real_estate_false.jar /real_estate_false.jar
COPY real_estate_false_lib /real_estate_false_lib
COPY resources /resources
COPY testxml /testxml
CMD ["java","-jar","/real_estate_false.jar",">","var/log/jar.log"]
```

Comment: Typo? "var/log/.." should it be "/var/log/.."?

Answer (score 1):

To just run myapp.jar in docker (e.g. to avoid installing java on the host) you can just run:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/mnt java:8 java -jar /mnt/myapp.jar
```

Comment: I like this example because for me it is the first one which clearly shows how to run an existing jar within a javarized docker container. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

The *exec* form of [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd) doesn't know what redirection is, that's a shell feature.

Either use stdout for logging.

```
CMD ["java","-jar","/real_estate_false.jar"]
```

If you really need a log file in the container, run the command in a shell

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "java -jar /real_estate_false.jar > var/log/jar.log"]
CMD java -jar /real_estate_false.jar > var/log/jar.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a logging file *inside* the container? Configuring a [logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) would be more flexible.

The following example is contrived, but demonstrates how logging events from all your containers could be collected. I suggest reading further into the options available from [fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/)

## Example

First run fluentd [within a container](https://hub.docker.com/r/fluent/fluentd/) to collect log events

```
mkdir log
docker run -d --name fluentd -p 24224:24224 -v $PWD:/fluentd/etc -v $PWD/log:/fluentd/log -e FLUENTD_CONF=log.conf fluent/fluentd
```

Now run a container that creates an event to be logged:

```
docker run --log-driver=fluentd ubuntu echo hello world
```

The sample configuration sends log events to an output log file

```
├── log
│   └── events.20160901.b53b670f22298bbcb
└── log.conf
```

### log.conf

```
<source>
  @type  forward
  port  24224
</source>

<match **>
   @type file
   path         /fluentd/log/events
   append       true
</match>
```

---

## Additional

Are you married to the Oracle JDK? The following Dockerfile would be considerable simpler:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/demo-1.0.jar /opt/demo/demo-1.0.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","/opt/demo/demo-1.0.jar"]
```