# running nodejs app in docker with redirecting standard output to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerfile, redirectstandardoutput

i have created a Dockerfile to run a nodejs app and would like to redirect its standard output to a file like that:
`CMD [ "node", "app.js", ">", "/usr/src/kuku.out", "2>&1"]`
but the file *kuku.out* is not being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [the "shell" form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd) of the `CMD` instruction, since redirects are shell constructs:

```
CMD node app.js > /usr/src/kuku.out 2>&1
```

Or explicitly start a shell yourself:

```
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "node app.js > /usr/src/kuku.out 2>&1" ]
```

(which is basically the same as the shell form)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use one of the [logging plugins](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) to redirect application output.

For a contrived example using the fluentd driver:

- [How to run jar file using docker file in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244768/how-to-run-jar-file-using-docker-file-in-docker-container/39260786#39260786)