# How to mount same dir in containers to different path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rancher

I am using rancher to deploy my docker containers and it may deploy two containers using the same image into same host. I wanna mount the log dir to host. I wanna mount them like this:

```
/var/log/container1/ -> log dir in container1
/var/log/container2/ -> log dir in container2
```

How can I do that with rancher and docker?

If I use -v with absolute path, the will mount to the same dir.if I use relative path , it will mount to the sharing volume mount point of docker. I don't want that.

Comment: Have you considered using a logging plugin instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244768/how-to-run-jar-file-using-docker-file-in-docker-container/39260786#39260786

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Do you mean the --log-driver argument?

Comment: Absolutely. The link I gave has a contrived example of using the fluentd logging driver